# Iterate or index list based on Enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, enums, enumeration

I have a small enum list of 4 elements (`class Type(Enum): One,Two,Three,Four`), and I'm wondering if there is a way to associate the enum with a global list (`List = [Type(0),Type(1),Type(2),Type(3)`].

I know I can access this list using the syntax `List[ Type.Two.value ]`. But I'm hoping there is a simple way to lose the `.value`. It's not a typing problem - I don't mind typing long descriptive variable names. But the list and enum are directly related/associated, so it would be preferable if the list respected the enum as an iterator. Is there a simple way to pull this off?

I'm working in the environment of Blender, building an add-on, if that makes any difference. I'm also very new to python altogether - about a week old, so do not omit obvious points if you have them.

I'm very familiar with C/C++, in case there are any similarities. I was a big fan of creating data library lists and associating iterator types in a way that prevented access to the list using anything other than the index typename associated with it (so you couldn't make a mistake like `Cars[my_boat_index]`)

I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning an `Enum` into a list is as easy as:

```
list(Type)
# [<Type.ONE: 1>, <Type.TWO: 2>, <Type.THREE: 3>, <Type.FOUR: 4>]
```

Accessing a list using `Type` members as indices is a little more complicated:

- by default, member values start at 1
- but container indices start at 0
- and members don't have the `__index__` and `__int__` methods

The easy/simple solution is twofold:

- use `IntEnum` instead of `Enum`
- start the counting at `0`

So:

```
class Type(IntEnum):
    ZERO = 0
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3
```

`IntEnum` members can be used anywhere an `int` is, so they work fine as index values.

The more complicated solution is to use a regular `Enum`, add in the methods you need, and subtract 1 when returning the value:

```
class Type(Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3
    FOUR = 4

    def __index__(self):
        return self.value - 1

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value - 1
```

Even if you go with adding the `__index__` and `__int__` methods, you should still just start counting at zero instead of doing the subtract one trick, as that will cause more problems later when you get used to the way Python works.

Comment: Looks like IntEnum is a good match for my situation. Thank you for explaining in so much detail.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're looking to restrict access to a list by restricting the type of the index to a specific type (e.g. an Enum).

Although I don't think it's a good idea, you can definitely do it:

```
from enum import Enum


class MyEnum(Enum):
    ZERO = 0
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2


class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        assert isinstance(item, MyEnum)
        return super().__getitem__(item.value)


ml = MyList([1, 2, 3])
print(ml[MyEnum.ONE])
print(ml[1])  # error here
```

Why would you want to restrict access to a list to a different type than the default type for list index (i.e. `int`) though?

If you're looking to have specific attributes, why not define a class, or if you want to index through specific values, why not use a dict?

Perhaps you should provide some information on what you're actually hoping to do - Python is not C/C++ and it probably has some perfectly valid way of doing what you want to do, without having to emulate what C/C++ does instead.

If you're not looking to restrict, but just to iterate (which seems to be distinct from what the question stated):

```
for my_value in MyEnum:
    print(ml[my_value])
```

You could then leave out the `assert` statement, if you're not interesting in limiting access to indices with that type only.

Comment: I'm not trying to restrict access to the list. Just iterate with enumerator values. The Blender environment seems to be very restrictive when it comes to defining custom types for properties, so I'm not sure what I can get away with yet. As for C/C++, I just mentioned that I'm familiar with it in case there were any similarities that would make the python situation easier to explain. No other reasons. Thanks for showing me this type of setup. I'm not sure Blender will allow me to create property groups, with a custom list type, but I'm going to give it a try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html  `Enumerations support iteration, in definition order`  so you can iterate over them to build lists, for example:

```
from enum import Enum

class Numbers(Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3

assert [Number.value for Number in Numbers]  == [1,2,3]
```